# How to get built-in calendars using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I want to get subscription calendar ('USOS' calendar from screenshot) but I can't filter built-in calendars such as 'US Holidays' or 'Święta w Polsce'. So my question is how to filter built-in calendars in other way than just filtering their name.

Screenshot from calendar:

[image: Screenshot from calendar]

After getting full access to events I'm doing this to get calendars

```
var calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: .event)
```

Then I tried to filter results with:

```
calendars = calendars.filter { $0.type == .subscription }
```

But there is still calendar 'Święta w Polsce'.

I also tried properties such as 'allowsContentModifications', 'isSubscribed' and 'isImmutable' but for 'Święta w Polsce' and subscription calendar all these properties have the same value.

Comment: The holidays calendar is a subscribed calendar, so you would expect all of those properties to be the same.  Even if you were able to filter that calendar you have to handle the situation where the user has multiple subscribed calendars. If you need to select a specific calendar you would need to show a list to the user and ask them to select the calendar they want to use.

Comment: What does `print ("isSubscribed:", calendar.isSubscribed)` show?

Comment: @Paulw11 I know that I need to have a list for the user to choose specific subscribed calendar, but I just don't want to show builtin calendars. I also know that holidays calendar is also subscribed but I thought that for example source will be different because imo builtin calendar is something different than calendar added by user

Comment: @admi126n, that's solid thinking, but in this case, there's a couple scenarios that work against that. 1- Things that appear in the Apple UI that aren't even available in the API -> "Siri Suggestions". 2- Calendars that are not "built-in", they are simply auto-provisioned by the account. Both Apple and Google do this, they provide their own holiday calendar for their calendar accounts.